# Are there any differences between school level, club level and international level Quidditch?

Tags: harry-potter, quidditch

Are there known differences between the different levels of quidditch play?

For instance, bludgers hitting harder and snitches being faster or more mobile for higher level play?

Comment: Is there any difference between school, college and pro level football? It's the same I guess ;-)

Comment: @Loki with football, the equipment is inert, so the quality of play and players are the only variables, but in something with more practical equipment, e.g. motor racing you have go-karts, Formula 5000, Formula 1. Strategies for F1 at 100mph+ is much different to 50mph in a tiny kart.

Comment: Fair enough, good point!

Comment: @StuperUser The "quality of play and players" aren't the only things that differ between school, college and professional (American) football. There are differences in the rules at the different levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes

The way the reply is "Never at Hogwarts" implies it has happened elsewhere so we can assume that the Bludgers are perhaps a bit more violent at the club and international levels.

> "Er -- have the Bludgers ever killed anyone?" Harry asked, hoping he sounded offhand.
>
> "**Never at Hogwarts.** We've had a couple of broken jaws but nothing worse than that.
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*, Chapter 10, "Halloween"</sub>

During the Quidditch World Cup there are trained mediwizards on stand by should they be needed.

> “It’s time-out!” yelled Bagman’s voice, “as trained mediwizards hurry onto the field to examine Aidan Lynch!”
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, Chapter 8, "The Quidditch World Cup"</sub>

These are likely not present during the matches at Hogwarts seeing as it was Dumbledore who stopped Harry from falling.

> "Dumbledore was really angry," Hermione said in a quaking voice. "I've never seen him like that before. **He ran onto the field as You fell, waved his wand, and you sort of slowed down before you hit the ground.** Then he whirled his wand at the dementors. Shot silver stuff at them. They left the stadium right away... He was furious they'd come onto the grounds. We heard him --"
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*, Chapter 9, "Grim Defeat"</sub>

We also know that Quidditch only ends when the Snitch is caught.

> "This," said Wood, "is the Golden Snitch, and it's the most important ball of the lot. It's very hard to catch because it's so fast and difficult to see. It's the Seeker's job to catch it. You've got to weave in and out of the Chasers, Beaters, Bludgers, and Quaffle to get it before the other team's Seeker, because whichever Seeker catches the Snitch wins his team an extra hundred and fifty points, so they nearly always win. That's why Seekers get fouled so much. **A game of Quidditch only ends when the Snitch is caught**, so it can go on for ages -- I think the record is three months, they had to keep bringing on substitutes so the players could get some sleep. "Well, that's it -- any questions?"
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*, Chapter 10, "Halloween"</sub>

However, if the Harry Potter Lexicon is to be believed games in the Quidditch World Cup will end at 4 hours if the Snitch has not been caught. I have yet to find the source for this though.

> - game length is a maximum of four hours
> - games where the Snitch hasn't been caught within four hours will be decided on the final goal score total
>
> <sub>[Harry Potter Lexicon, Quidditch World Cup](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/thing/quidditch-world-cup/)</sub>

Although the Lexicon might be wrong here as we see some games can take longer:

> ‘Look at the time,’ Mrs Weasley said suddenly, checking her wristwatch. ‘You really should be in bed, the whole lot of you, you’ll be up at the crack of dawn to get to the Cup. Harry, if you leave your school list out, I’ll get your things for you tomorrow in Diagon Alley. I’m getting everyone else’s. **There might not be time after the World Cup, the match went on for five days last time.’**